# Show raster from postgis via mapserver

Tags: database, postgis, mapserver

I would like to show raster from database. I read article [How can I add a PostGIS raster layer to my MapServer map?](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html)  and created mapfile according by this. I get 500 - Internal server error.

When I display this raster in QGIS via PostGIS, the error message from mapserver is empty. I can read with mapserver to show vector data from the same database.

Have you some idea how solve this?

Part of mapfile with layer:

```
LAYER
  NAME eroze_cp

  TYPE raster

  STATUS ON

  DATA "PG:host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='mydb' user='me' password='****' schema='myschema' table='myrast' mode='2'" 

  PROJECTION

    "init=epsg:102067"

  END 

  PROCESSING "NODATA=-9999"

  PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"

END
```

Comment: Are you using Mapserver with Apache?  You should check the server log.  That's easily the best place to start.  In your mapfile, you can specify the location of the mapserver log file.     CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/tmp/ms_error.txt" .  Once you do that, tail the file with something like "tail -f -n 500 /tmp/ms_error.txt" .  Refresh you page and you should see a nice error in your log.  Paste that back here and you'll probably get a much better answer.

Comment: File with errors is blank. I increased timeout for 90 sec for solving Internal Server Error (500). Then I limited raster for several rids and raster has displayed. Do I have a chance for displaying all (20 000) rids? DATA "PG:host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='mydb' user='me' password='****' schema='myschema' table='myrast' where='rid IN (9814,9815,9816,9817)' mode='2'"

Comment: My connection looks more like this...        CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
        CONNECTION "host=*** dbname=** user=** password=**"
        TYPE LINE
        LABELCACHE ON
        LABELITEM "owner"
        PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
        DATA "wkt_geometry from ne_dw_cables"

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can try is to use shp2img at the command line, to get more info about errors.

Look at:
http://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html#idp35570592

You appear to have extra quotes in the connection string, althought I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: Thank you for rensponse. Quotes are away now but the problem there is still. How I can use shp2img? I can use it on Windows, but this mapfile is on Linux. I cant find it.

Comment: You are going to have to debug it on Linux. try "locate shp2img" on Linux to find the command.  If its not there try: "/path/to/mapserv QUERY_STRING='<query string>" where <query_string> is all the text after /?/ in the url.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Example of WMS-T with PostGIS Tile Index for Raster Imagery](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_time.html#example-of-wms-t-with-postgis-tile-index-for-raster-imagery) from the Mapserver docs (there's another example at [MapServer TILEINDEXes with Database RASTERS](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/MapServer-TILEINDEXes-with-Database-RASTERS)). With a Postgis-backed database, you create a `TILEINDEX` view.  Then you add two layers to your `mapfile`, like so:

Tile Index layer:

```
LAYER
  name raster_tindex
  TYPE polygon
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:xxxx"
  END
  CONNECTIONTYPE ORACLESPATIAL
  CONNECTION "user/pass@tns"
  DATA "geom FROM (
    SELECT gid, geom, location 
    FROM my_raster_tindex_table
  ) AS subquery using unique gid USING SRID=4326"
END
```

Second layer which is the actual RASTER layer

```
LAYER
  name db_raster_layer
  TYPE RASTER
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:xxxx"
  END
  TILEINDEX "raster_tindex"   #THIS NAME MUST MATCH THE TILEINDEX LAYER NAME
  TILEITEM "location"   #not actually needed if column is named location
  STATUS OFF
  OFFSITE 0 0 0
END
```

You can filter on TIME by adding a FILTER to `db_raster_layer`, as with [the WMS-T example in the MapServer docs](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_time.html#example-of-wms-t-with-postgis-tile-index-for-raster-imagery).  However, a FILTER on properties/attributes of the data should live on the Tile Index (ie. in the `raster_tindex` layer), as mentioned [by Frank Warmerdam in ogr tileindex with postgis?](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2007-October/025706.html)